# How to import wiring csv into cad?

Tags: pcb-design, trace, cad

I have a .csv file which contains the (complicated) points of the paths that I need my wires to trace. I would normally use EasyEda for making grbl files, but I don't think it is capable. Is there a pcb cad program that can import custom csv files as circuit wiring? If so, which one and how do I go about doing that?

These .csv files are simple 2xN matrices:

```
134.21159,14.568773
134.092875,15.623726
133.965868,16.677713
133.830577,17.730669
133.68701,18.782528
133.535176,19.833226
133.375084,20.882697
133.206744,21.930877
133.030167,22.977701
132.845363,24.023104
132.670293,24.971849
132.652344,25.067021
132.451122,26.109389
132.24171,27.150141
132.02412,28.189215
131.798365,29.226545
131.56446,30.262069
131.32242,31.29572
131.072258,32.327437
130.813991,33.357154
130.796759,33.424659
130.547635,34.384809
130.273205,35.410337
129.99072,36.433675
129.700196,37.454761
129.401652,38.47353
129.095105,39.48992
128.979468,39.865985
128.780576,40.503868
128.458082,41.515312
128.127645,42.524188
127.789285,43.530434
127.443022,44.533989
127.2146,45.18236
127.088878,45.534789
126.726875,46.532774
```

Comment: I know nothing about EasyEda or grbl but your data is just a list of points. For line segments I would expect pairs of points, line width and layer information.

Comment: I was hoping I could give the cad (Eagle, Altium, Easyeda) a set of points, and then fill out the rest (width,depth,etc) using the cad software.

Comment: Most CAD software lets you hook into it with some scripting language for doing things like this, but I doubt there's going to be a dedicated system for it. Write your own script to do it.

Comment: @user1402154 Your data look like a dash and dot line style arc in my CAD. The problem is: This CAD is self written and you would hate it like everyone (except me). If you just want to convert your CSV in RS274X this will be ok.

Comment: will JLCPCB or any other pcb manufacturing company accept something like RS274X?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, figured it out.

1. import that csv into freeCad by running a script in the terminal which loads files:

```py
from FreeCAD import Base
import Draft, Part
file = open("good2dCoil.csv")
wire = []
X=Y=Z = 0.0

for ligne in file:
    coordinates = ligne.split(",")
    try:                                                        # for format PCD ignore the header
        X,Y = coordinates                                     # separate the coordinates
        print(X," ",Y)
        wire.append(FreeCAD.Vector(float(X),float(Y))) # append the coordinates
    except Exception:
        None
file.close()
Draft.makeWire(wire,closed=False,face=False,support=None)   # create the wire open

App.ActiveDocument.recompute()
```

2. export it as dxf
3. import it into the pcb generator of Kicad
4. make my changes and generate pcb